# I'm using the menu button in extjs7.4, but the icon image doesn't appear

Tags: button, extjs, menu

I using [extjs](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/) version 7.4.

The icon is clearly visible in the example of Sencha.
https://examples.sencha.com/extjs/7.4.0/examples/kitchensink/#menu-buttons

However, icon isn't displayed in my actual code
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F8Yy5.png)

Is there a problem with my source? Or is it a Sencha bug?

--- source ---

```
Ext.define('test.view.main.MainController', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.ViewController',

    alias: 'controller.main',

    toggleDisabled: function(checkbox, checked) {
        var view = this.getView(),
            stateFn = checked ? 'disable' : 'enable',
            buttons = view.query('button');

        Ext.each(buttons, function(btn) {
            btn[stateFn]();
        });
    }
});

Ext.define('test.view.main.Main', {
    extend: 'Ext.Container',
    xtype: 'menu-buttons',
    controller: 'main',

    layout: 'vbox',
    width: 470,

    items: [{
        xtype: 'checkbox',
        boxLabel: 'Disabled',
        margin: '0 0 0 10',
        listeners: {
            change: 'toggleDisabled'
        }
    }, {
        xtype: 'container',
        layout: {
            type: 'table',
            columns: 4,
            tdAttrs: { style: 'padding: 5px 10px;' }
        },
        defaults: {
            menu: [{
                text: 'Menu Item 1'
            }, {
                text: 'Menu Item 2'
            }, {
                text: 'Menu Item 3'
            }]
        },

        items: [{
            xtype: 'component',
            html: 'Text Only'
        }, {
            xtype: 'button',
            text: 'Small'
        }, {
            xtype: 'button',
            text: 'Medium',
            scale: 'medium'
        }, {
            xtype: 'button',
            text: 'Large',
            scale: 'large'
        }, {
            xtype: 'component',
            html: 'Icon Only'
        }, {
            iconCls: 'button-home-small',
            xtype: 'button'
        }, {
            xtype: 'button',
            iconCls: 'button-home-medium',
            scale: 'medium'
        }, {
            xtype: 'button',
            iconCls: 'button-home-large',
            scale: 'large'
        }, {
            xtype: 'component',
            html: 'Icon and Text (left)'
        }, {
            xtype: 'button',
            iconCls: 'button-home-small',
            text: 'Small'
        }, {
            xtype: 'button',
            iconCls: 'button-home-medium',
            text: 'Medium',
            scale: 'medium'
        }, {
            xtype: 'button',
            iconCls: 'button-home-large',
            text: 'Large',
            scale: 'large'
        }, {
            xtype: 'component',
            html: 'Icon and Text (top)'
        }, {
            xtype: 'button',
            iconCls: 'button-home-small',
            text: 'Small',
            iconAlign: 'top'
        }, {
            xtype: 'button',
            iconCls: 'button-home-medium',
            text: 'Medium',
            scale: 'medium',
            iconAlign: 'top'
        }, {
            xtype: 'button',
            iconCls: 'button-home-large',
            text: 'Large',
            scale: 'large',
            iconAlign: 'top'
        }, {
            xtype: 'component',
            html: 'Icon and Text (right)'
        }, {
            xtype: 'button',
            iconCls: 'button-home-small',
            text: 'Small',
            iconAlign: 'right'
        }, {
            xtype: 'button',
            iconCls: 'button-home-medium',
            text: 'Medium',
            scale: 'medium',
            iconAlign: 'right'
        }, {
            xtype: 'button',
            iconCls: 'button-home-large',
            text: 'Large',
            scale: 'large',
            iconAlign: 'right'
        }, {
            xtype: 'component',
            html: 'Icon and Text (bottom)'
        }, {
            xtype: 'button',
            iconCls: 'button-home-small',
            text: 'Small',
            iconAlign: 'bottom'
        }, {
            xtype: 'button',
            iconCls: 'button-home-medium',
            text: 'Medium',
            scale: 'medium',
            iconAlign: 'bottom'
        }, {
            xtype: 'button',
            iconCls: 'button-home-large',
            text: 'Large',
            scale: 'large',
            iconAlign: 'bottom'
        }]
    }]
});
```

I've been looking into it for days, but I can't find a solution.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you missed to define the classes like here:

[image]

---

As an alternative you can try to set the icon like that:

- iconCls:'x-fa fa-home'

Which prefix you will need depends on your FontAwesome version.

Following this approach you might need additional classes to scale the icon. But i am not sure.

Comment: Thank you very much for your great help. Thanks to you, it was solved well.

The biggest reason for my lack of experience is...
I think it was hard for me to understand because KitchenSink did not disclose the related class. (Maybe I didn't find it.))

I think "choosing extjs was the wrong decision."

Once again, thank you very much.